# Why does SO tell me that the post is already closed when I vote to close?

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I've seen this a couple of times in the Review Close Votes queue. I vote to close the question, but then a box pops up that tells me it's already closed, and to refresh the page.

I understand that the post was closed while I was still reviewing it, but *I don't understand why I am being told*.

- The question is already closed, so my close vote can safely be ignored
- It breaks flow because I have to close the message box, and then refresh the review queue.

I expect to just be bumped along to the next question automatically. Why isn't that happening?

Comment: This happens when the question is being closed after the review item was already loaded.

Comment: I understand the the item was closed while I was reviewing it, but I don't understand why the review queue *feels the need to tell me*. I expect it to take me to the next item to review without interrupting me.

Comment: It's a standard error handling mechanism. There was error while submitting the review action to the server, it just happens that the error happened due to the question being closed in the time of submission. You'll get similar popup if there will be unexpected internal error in the server as well, or if the network connection will time out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I expect to just be bumped along to the next question automatically. Why isn't that happening?

I guess that is just a matter of opinions. I like to be told that the my vote won't be applied because it really wasn't applied. Also, I don't get the *flow* part. It is not about closing them as fast as you can and stacking up the daily limit as fast as possible (I'm not saying you do that) but I don't think being notified is breaking anything.

You see, I personally think that it would be bad design to not tell me that my vote wasn't applied on the closing process. Users could go on the post, not see their name and come here to ask the question *Hey ! I closed that question ! But my name isn't there*.

Anyways, this is by-design and I do not think it will change any time soon.